# Interactive "open with" dialog mod?

Tags: usability, dialog

I switched to Ubuntu this year from Windows. I like Ubuntu, but what I'm missing is smart "Open with" dialog. You should manually search for a program either from long list without ability to filter, either from disk and I don't even know where are my programs. This is what Ubuntu provides out of the box. Is there any modification which will allow easy search and pick up a program to open a file in "open with" dialog? It should work like when we type in a program name in "Search your computer" screen on win key.

Comment: i could think of a custom script that lets you select a program and pass selected file to it, but it won't save the program . Are you looking for single-shot or something that remembers the selected program ?

Comment: I think it should be like easy search for a needed program and once a file has been opened with some program it should be displayed in "open with" context menu list. This is how it works in windows, it's convenient.

Comment: Yes, i understand that. My question is , do you want that dialog to remember selected program and always open file with that program, or can it be just one-time choice

Comment: @Serg one time choice is enough, I think. To change  file associations manually is not that difficult, but maybe there should be some checkbox in the dialog, to remember association which is in False state by default.

Comment: OK , I will be working on a script . Once I have something working , I will let you know

Comment: Answer posted. Let me know what you think . If you need translation to Russian, let me know - I can provide that as well.

Answer (score 1):

#### Script Intro

This script allows choosing a file, selecting an application from file selection dialog, open user selected file with that application, and optionally setting that same application as default.

Since the script uses file dialog , you can select a `.desktop` file of an application from anywhere in the filesystem. For instance, if you have one in `/opt` directory, you can easily navigate there. By default , dialog starts out in `/usr/share/applications` since that's where most applications place their `.desktop` files.

This script is meant to be added to Nautilus as right click option.

#### Installation

The script is posted here and on my personal [github repository](https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep). Simplest way would be via `wget` command :

```
   cd $HOME/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/ && wget -O select_application.py  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SergKolo/sergrep/master/select_application.py  && chmod +x select_application.py
```

If you have `git` installed , you can install it via the following steps.

1. `cd /tmp`
2. `git clone https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep.git`
3. `mv /tmp/sergrep/select_application.py $HOME/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`
4. `chmod +x $HOME/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/select_application.py`

#### How it works:

After installation, user can right click on a file

[image]

Choosing the `select_application.py` will bring up the following dialog. ( Note: typing in the initial few letters of a program does allow for auto-focus of specific file. )

[image]

Choose the application which you want to open your file. Finally you will be asked to set that application as default or not:

[image]

#### Script source code

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
###########################################################
# Author: Serg Kolo , contact: 1047481448@qq.com 
# Date: July 11, 2016 
# Purpose: Alternative "Open With" software for Nautilus
#          filemanager
# 
# Written for: http://askubuntu.com/q/797571/295286
# Tested on: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
###########################################################
# Copyright: Serg Kolo , 2016
#    
#     Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software is 
#     hereby granted without fee, provided that  the copyright notice 
#     above and this permission statement appear in all copies.
#
#     THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, 
#     EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF 
#     MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
#     IN NO EVENT SHALL  THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY 
#     CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, 
#     TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE 
#     SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.


import subprocess
import sys
import os
import getpass

def run_sh(cmd):
    # run shell commands, return stdout
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = p.stdout.read().strip()
    return out 

def extract_command(desktop_file):
    # read .desktop file , return command it  runs
    command=""
    with open(desktop_file) as file:
        for line in file:
            if "Exec=" in line:
                for string in  line.split('Exec=')[1].split():
                    if "%" not in string:
                      command = command + string + " "
                break
    return  command

def set_as_default( mime , desk_file  ):
    # add the .desktop file to list of apps assigned to 
    # mime types in mimeapps.list file
    # TODO : find out if Nautilus automatically creates this file
    #        or do we need to ensure that it exists ?
    defaults_file = '/home/' + getpass.getuser() \
                    + '/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list'
    temp_file = '/tmp/new_files'
    write_file = open(temp_file,'w')

    defaults_found = False
    mime_found = False
    with open(defaults_file) as read_file:
        for line in read_file:
            if '[Default Applications]' in line:
                defaults_found = True
            if defaults_found and mime in line:
                write_file.write( mime + '=' + desk_file + "\n" )
                mime_found = True
            else:
                write_file.write( line.strip() + "\n" )


    if not mime_found :
       write_file.write( mime_type + '=' + desktop_file + "\n" )

    write_file.close()
    os.rename(temp_file,defaults_file) 

#--------------

def main():

    # Open file dialog, let user choose program by its .desktop file
    filepath = run_sh('zenity --file-selection --file-filter="*.desktop" \
                              --filename="/usr/share/applications/" ')
    if filepath == "" :
       sys.exit(1)

    # Get the program user wants to run
    program = extract_command(filepath)

    # Find out the mimetype of the file user wants opened
    mime_type = run_sh("file --mime-type " \
                       + sys.argv[1]  ).split(':')[1].strip()

    # Extract just the .desktop filename itself
    desktop_file = filepath.split('/')[-1]

    # Check if user wants this program as default
    return_code = subprocess.call( [ 'zenity', '--question', '--title=""',
                      '--text="Would you like to set this app as' + \
                       ' default for this filetype?"'])

    if return_code == 0 :
       set_as_default( mime_type , desktop_file )

    # Finally, launch the program with file user chose
    # Can't use run_sh() because it expects stdout
    proc = subprocess.Popen( "nohup " + program + " " + sys.argv[1] \
                             + " &> /dev/null &" , shell=True)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```